# How to get all keys and values of the PlayerPrefs in Unity?

Tags: unity, unityscript

I'm storing player name and scores in the Unity PlayerPrefs. I'd like to list all the names and scores stored in PlayerPrefs and display a high score page:

[image]

Is it possible to display all the keys values previously stored in the PlayerPrefs? Or can someone provide me by a JavaScript to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not possible to get the names of the PlayerPrefs keys at runtime. Instead you could opt for serializing your highscore table, and adding it as a string value to a fixed key in PlayerPrefs.

This is untested C#, but you'll figure it out:

```
// Load highscores.
string highscoresSerialized = PlayerPrefs.GetString("highscores", "");
Dictionary<string,int> highscores = MyUnserialize(highscoresSerialized);

// Update highscores.
highscores["Xavier"] = 100;

// Show highscores.
foreach ( var entry in highscores )
{
    print(entry.Key + ": " + entry.Value);
}

// Save highscores.
string highscoresSerializedAgain = MySerialize(highscores);
PlayerPrefs.SetString("highscores", highscoresSerializedAgain);
PlayerPrefs.Save();
```

`MySerialize` is a function that should turn a `Dictionary<string,int>` into a string (e.g., `"Scott:100;Henry:200;Jean:150"`) and `MyUnserialize` should perform the reverse operation.